# Meaning of quantum orbitals with $\ell=0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, experimental-physics, orbitals, quantum-measurements

My question is simple:

1. Does a quantum eigenstate with orbital angular momentum $\ell=0$ meaning that the velocity of the particle is only radial when measured?
2. What is the experimental method to find if an electron is in an orbital with $\ell=0$ or $\ell = 1, 2, \ldots$?

Comment: I suppose the simplest way to measure angular momentum is to find the magnetic field, created by rotation of this electron and subtraction a spin of electron from it. In the same way for hydrogen atom, but oppositely by subtraction of angular momentum the spin of electron was discovered and measured.

Comment: We can't measure states directly. We can only measure state transitions. Even of we try to actually "x-ray" an atom to detect the charge distribution, we will find a radial distribution unless the orbitals are "pinned" in place with an external electric or magnetic field, otherwise the angular dependence of states with l>0 averages out because the atoms can "rotate" freely. x-ray crystallography does, however, work nicely on solids where the atoms are "oriented" in the local field of their neighbors.

Comment: if it’s an eigenstate the probability density does not depend on time so there is no “velocity” of anything.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Does a quantum eigenstate with orbital angular momentum $\ell=0$ meaning that the velocity of the particle is only radial when measured?

In the bound state you describe, the "eigenstate $\ell=0$" is a specific wavefunction $Ψ$ , and the specific  $Ψ^*Ψ$ describes the probability that the electron is at a specific (r,θ,φ) around the nucleus. The $l=0$ wavfunctions predicts a probability for the electron to be in the nucleus. Note , **probability**. To measure a probability one needs a lot of the same events , and then the prediction of the theory can be tested.

2. What is the experimental method to find if an electron is in an orbital with $\ell=0$ or $\ell = 1, 2, \ldots$?

The main experimental method of discovering the energy level of the orbital is scattering with photons of a known energy, and then the distributions can be checked for angular correlations to see what the $l$ value of the orbital is.

There is this [interesting experiment](https://physicsworld.com/a/quantum-microscope-peers-into-the-hydrogen-atom/)  using more complicated physics functions that can map orbitals, but not $l=0$  ones.